# CSS: Removing outer left and right margin on wrapping flex items

Tags: css

I am trying to remove outer left and right margins on the first and last items in a row of flex items.  Using `nth()` isn't an option since the first and last in a row will be dynamic depending on screen size.  The only option I found for the below code was to add a negative margin to the container:

```
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
```

but that feels "hacky".  Are there are any other solutions?

```css
body, html {
  background: grey;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;  
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container div {
  height: 60px;
  flex: 1 1 600px;
  background: green;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even the most famous framework does it that way. I think you can use it with peace of mind. No other solution comes to mind. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#example

Comment: It's not hacky..it's a good solution.
Another solution is using grid

Comment: _“but that feels "hacky"”_ - why? Giving anything a _positive_ margin to achieve what was needed in the current situation, probably (rarely) ever felt hacky, right? So what’s different here now?

Answer (score -1):

```
body, html {
      background: grey;
      height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;  
      height: 100%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .container div {
      height: 60px;
      flex: 1 1 600px;
      background: green;
      margin: 20px 0px;
    }
```